# Flask-sentinel /oauth/token endpoint CORS issue

Tags: python, flask, oauth, eve

I'm having issues trying to get a token from my flask-sentinel app with my front-end.

To make the AJAX requests from my front-end to my [Python Eve](http://docs.python-eve.org) API server I use the [superagent](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent) module.

While using a Basic Authentication I don't have any issue getting data from my endpoints. See code below:

```
superagent
    .get( 'http://192.168.1.x:5000/endpoint' )
    .auth( this.params.username, this.params.password )
    .on( 'error', this.onError )
    .then( this.onSuccess );
```

If I try to request a token to the `/oauth/token` endpoint with this code:

```
superagent
    .post( 'http://192.168.1.x:5000/oauth/token' )
    .set( 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' )
    .send( 'grant_type=password&client_id='+this.params.client_id+'&username='+this.params.username+'&password='+this.params.password )
    .on( 'error', this.onError )
    .then( this.onTokenReceived );
```

I get a CORS error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.1.x:5000/oauth/token' from origin 'http://192.168.1.y:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Here are the settings of my application (omitting the database and domain settings):

```
SENTINEL_X_DOMAINS           = ['http://192.168.1.y:3000']
SENTINEL_X_HEADERS           = ['Authorization','Content-type','If-Match','Access-Control-Allow-Origin']
SENTINEL_X_EXPOSE_HEADERS    = SENTINEL_X_HEADERS
SENTINEL_RESOURCE_METHODS    = ['GET','HEAD','PUT','PATCH','POST','DELETE','OPTIONS']
SENTINEL_PUBLIC_METHODS      = SENTINEL_RESOURCE_METHODS
SENTINEL_X_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

X_DOMAINS           = ['http://192.168.1.y:3000']
X_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
X_HEADERS           = ['Authorization','Content-type','If-Match','Access-Control-Allow-Origin']
RESOURCE_METHODS    = ['GET','HEAD','PUT','PATCH','POST','DELETE','OPTIONS']
```

Can you please guide me in getting what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: maybe useful? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that because the content-type is not text/plain, the browser is issuing an [OPTIONS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS) request. and as stated in the console error the response does not set the '[Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin)' header.

From looking at [Eve's docs](http://docs.python-eve.org/en/latest/config.html), it seems you need to set the X_EXPOSE_HEADERS variable with ['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] that:

> "Allows API maintainers to specify which headers are exposed within a
>   CORS response. Allowed values are: None or a list of headers names.
>   Defaults to None."

The browser expects to receive the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', thus the failure.
Try to allow this header in the response from the API

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tested that solution and unfortunately it does not work. I have managed to make it work in another way. I will make an answer as soon as I have some time.

Answer (score 0):

In your Flask app, try setting the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in your response, i.e.,

```
response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
```

That should most likely solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I can't do something like that in Eve.

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted out how to fix this though I am not completely satisfied.

Here the steps I've followed:

- I have forked the [Flask Sentinel](https://github.com/pyeve/flask-sentinel) repository
- I have installed [Flas-CORS](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with Pip
- I have edited the `flask_sentinel/flask_sentinel.py` file by importing flask_cors
- Before [this line](https://github.com/pyeve/flask-sentinel/blob/master/flask_sentinel/flask_sentinel.py#L26) I've inserted this piece of code:

```
CORS(app, origins=['http://192.168.1.y:3000','https://192.168.1.y:3000'])
```

- I went back to my Eve project and installed Flask-Sentinel through my forked repository with Pip instead of the original one

Comment: Instead of forking and editing `flask-sentinel` itself, you could import the `ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentials`, subclass it, and in the `__init__`  method of your subclass you could do the `CORS` initiation and then run the `__init__` method of the superclass. You can then use your subclass instead of `ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentials` directly.